# What is the difference between SqlCeConnection and SqlConnection C#?

Tags: c#, database

I am using Eclipse with its database. I am using SqlCeConnection for connecting however, it doesn't seem to hold the data I don't know why. When I right click on the db and say "show table data", it shows inside null.

I saw SqlConnection. What is the difference between SqlCeConnection and SqlConnection? And do you have any idea why there is no table data in my database?

Comment: What DB are you connecting to? The [SqlServerCe namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec4st0e3(v=VS.100).aspx) is for the Compact edition of SQL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) is for SQL Server Databases

[SqlCeConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cty35hs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is for the [Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)